# How to evaluate series whose terms are constructed from terms in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I came across this question on my test a while back.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of integers with $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1}$ = $a_n$ + $a_{n-1}$ for all natural $n$ and $n>1$.

Find $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}$ and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}$.

[This is a new concept to me and I haven't tried much apart from linking  $a_{n+1}$ = $a_n$ + $a_{n-1}$ to $x^2-x-1$ using the Newton formula. Also, I read something about the concept that the quadratic equation I got was a "characteristic equation" and the closed form of the series is $S=A \alpha^n + B \beta^n$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants.]

Answer (score 2):

For the first sum
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}$$

so
$$a_{n}=a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}.a_{n-1}}$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n+1}.a_{n-1}}$$

Now it can be solved by telescoping method
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}$$

Answer (score -1):

For second sum.

Multiply and divide by $a_{n}$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}.a_n.a_{n+1}}$$

now $a_n = a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}$.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}.a_n.a_{n+1}}$$

Split the numerator
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a_{n-1}.a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n}.a_{n+1}}$$
This can again be solves by telescoping method.
So
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a_{n-1}.a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n}.a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_1.a_2}$$

Comment: Yes i had got this but thanks a lot! Could you tell me more about what i tried and how it can be used?

Comment: @User0 Actually I am high school student and don't know much about what you have tried. But I know that there is formula for general term of Fibonacci sequence. You can google it

Comment: ah same, its was from a jee mains paper.